# Changing a for loop with a set number of iterations to an indefinite while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to adjust the following so that instead of running at most 10 times and then "giving up", it just runs indefinitely until it hits an answer. I could just jack the range up to a stupendous number but that's cheating isn't it.

```
def f(x):
    return x**2-2

def bisection(f,a,b): 
    for i in range (10):
        c=(a+b)/2
        if abs(f(c))<1/10**10:
            print("found zero",c)
            return c
        if f(a)*f(c)<0:
            a=a 
            b=c
        else: 
            a=c
            b=b 
        print("a=",a,"b=",b,"f(a)=",f(a))

bisection(f,0,2)
```

I tried swapping the

```
for i in range (10):
```

with

```
c=(a+b)/2
while abs(f(c))<1/10**10:
```

I get nothing. Nothing prints, no errors either. Baffled.

I'd appreciate some help

Thanks!

Comment: Simplest variant: Replace `for`-loop with `while True:`

Comment: @MichaelButscher Oh wow, thanks a lot!

Comment: @MichaelButscher That should be an answer, I believe

Comment: @DavidZ I hesitate to write such a simple one-liner as an answer, even if it technically is one.

Comment: No problem, then; I've posted it myself. (I had the same idea as you did but held off on posting it to give you a chance to get the answer in first - but if you'd rather not, I'll go for it.)

Comment: @Carcigenicate Oh yeah that's right.I just tried flipping the equality sign and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to replace the `for ...:` with `while True:`. That simply removes the 10-iteration limit.